# How do I correct the following code in django, It's give an error "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)"

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

```
<script>
 var CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token }}';
    function getQuestion(str)
    {

        if(str!="select subject")
    {
        var req=new XMLHttpRequest();


        req.open("post","/addQuestion/",true);
        str=encodeURIComponent(str);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send("subject="+str);
        req.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(req.status==200 && req.readyState==4)
            {
                document.getElementById("formdiv").innerHTML=req.responseText;
                document.getElementById("formdiv").style.overflowY="scroll";

            }
        }

    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're never passing your CSRF token with your request.

Comment: how can i pass csrf token with request?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should set CSRF_TOKEN in request header

```
req.setRequestHeader('CSRF_TOKEN', CSRF_TOKEN);
```